# How to access my own google calendar without making public

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I want to display my own calendar events details on website.

For this I have tried by using google API call with API key and Calendar ID.
But issue faced during this i need to make calendar as "Public".

Once I make calendar as public event details are being fetched but when I remove calendar as public issue occurred as error 404 "Not found".

What should I need to get details of calendar events without making calendar as public.

I am using this code:

```
var mykey = 'Gtg-rtZdsreUr_fLfhgPfgff'; 
var calendarid = '3ruy234vodf6hf4sdf5sd84f@group.calendar.google.com'; 

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: encodeURI('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarid+ '/events?key=' + mykey),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        //do whatever you want with each
    },
    error: function (response) {
        //tell that an error has occurred
    }
});
```

Comment: Check out service accounts

Answer (score 0):

You can use service accounts.

> A service account's credentials include a generated email address that
>   is unique, a client ID, and at least one public/private key pair.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

```
<?php

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/autoload.php');

$client_email = '1234567890-a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('MyProject.p12');
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin');
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$sqladmin = new Google_Service_SQLAdmin($client);
$response = $sqladmin->instances
    ->listInstances('examinable-example-123')->getItems();
echo json_encode($response) . "\n";
```